# Python: issues in reading and printing Turkish with Turkish letters

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding

I'm having the following problems in reading and printing Turkish in python, the Turkish letters in the word cannot be recognized. But such problem doesn't arise when I try to store strings on other languages such as Russian, Japanese and Chinese.

```
>>> s = u'abartmadığını'
>>> s
u'abartmad???n?'
>>> print s
abartmad???n?
```

How can I adjust the encoding to solve this problem? I am using Python 2.7.10 on Windows 10 and changing the code page of command line to 28595 doesn't seem to work, I just got the following error in python console.

> LookupError: unknown encoding: cp28595

Comment: Maybe you might need to accept using non-Turkish letters, because Turkish letters might not be usable in unicode.

Comment: @FranzNoel nope, the same thing works well on Mac OS, there must be some issues with the environment

Comment: Works well on Linux. Must be something with Windows 10. Are you using the CMD terminal?

Comment: Are you typing that directly at the console?  That's likely not going to work without a Turkish version of Windows, or configuring the Windows system locale to Turkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows console is notorious for not supporting Unicode well.  Use an IDE that supports UTF-8 output.  Here's an example from PythonWin, part of the `pywin32` third-party module:

```
PythonWin 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.
Portions Copyright 1994-2008 Mark Hammond - see 'Help/About PythonWin' for further copyright information.
>>> s = u'abartmadığını. 我是美国人。 ру́сский язы́к'
>>> s
u'abartmad\u0131\u011f\u0131n\u0131. \u6211\u662f\u7f8e\u56fd\u4eba\u3002 \u0440\u0443\u0301\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u044f\u0437\u044b\u0301\u043a'
>>> print s
abartmadığını. 我是美国人。 ру́сский язы́к
```

Comment: Mark is right, even today unicode and windows console do have serious bugs.

Comment: This module specifically targets the Windows Console: https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console

Answer (score 2):

Encode it to utf-8

```
>>> s = u'abartmadığını'

>>> print s.encode('utf-8')

abartmadığını
```

Comment: That only works if the console encoding is configured for UTF-8, which isn't likely the case on Windows.

Comment: You should not encode when printing! stdout already has an encoding applied so you'll potentially double encode and will make your code non-platform agnostic. If users have errors when printing, then they should investigate the underlying issue. In this case, the user is using Windows, so encoding for the console is not the solution.